# Determine vertex in a "Isosceles Right Triangle"

Tags: math, geometry

Hi I have geometrical problem which is driving me crazy. I want to determine the location of one vertex in a "Isosceles Right Triangle" (alpha = 45°; beta = 45°; gamma = 90°).

E.g. in this illustration:
[image]

I have a,b,c,h and the location of A and B (and of cause the angle). The only thing thats missing is C in x,y terms. Can someone support me on this?

Comment: I would read up about matrices and there use in rotation. -  i.e. rotate the triangle first to lake life easier. Use `sine/cosine` etc to do the maths. The reverse the rotation. Do the algebra and the formula should come out of that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: a move would be great (is it possible?). But the question was with programming background even if its not written in the question. The answer piked this up and suggested an Python  approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code that works only for the 45°-45°-90° triangle--it would need to be modified  for other triangles.

Note that all you need are the coordinates of `A` and `B`. `c` is then the distance between those two points, `h` is `c/2`, and both `a` and `b` are `c/sqrt(2)`. This Python code returns a 2-tuple `(Cx, Cy)` giving the coordinates of `C`, assuming you want `C` to be oriented counterclockwise from the vector `AB`. If you want clockwise, replace the plus sign with a minus sign in the calculation that defines `inclinationAC`. This uses only basic trigonometry, showing each step--there are other methods, as Ed Heal says in his comment, but this should be more easily understood by most people.

```
from math import sqrt, hypot, pi, cos, sin, atan2

def corner_right_isoceles(Ax, Ay, Bx, By):
    """Return the coordinates of the right-angle corner of a right
    isosceles triangle if the other two vertices are the points
    (Ax, Ay) and (Bx, By). The returned corner is counterclockwise
    from the vector AB.
    """
    c = hypot(By - Ay, Bx - Ax)
    b = c / sqrt(2)
    inclinationAB = atan2(By - Ay, Bx - Ax)
    inclinationAC = inclinationAB + pi / 4
    Cx = Ax + b * cos(inclinationAC)
    Cy = Ay + b * sin(inclinationAC)
    return Cx, Cy
```

Comment: absolutely brilliant. It's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another version, which is a bit simpler and with that also much more efficient to calculate. The idea is that `h` is exactly half of `c` in this triangle:

```
dx = Bx - Ax
dy = By - Ay
Cx = Ax + 0.5 * (dx - dy)
Cy = Ay + 0.5 * (dy + dx)
```